# WebDriver PhantomJS Unable to find element, but works fine with Firefox

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, phantomjs

I have been banging my head into the wall for a long time now so I thought I would ask the "experts" why the below code would not work (entering password) with PhantomJS but works just fine with Firefox. The most disturbing of all is that one field entry (username) is successful but the second would not work at all. The page loads just fine and I have included test code to verify other components are loaded just fine.

See code below:

```
import java.io.File;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver;

public class login {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebDriver driver;
    Boolean verbose = false;  //Change to true to test it with firefox
    String phantomPath = "../phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-i686/bin/phantomjs";
    String url = "https://www.britishairways.com/travel/redeem/execclub/_gf/en_us";

    if (verbose) {
         driver = new FirefoxDriver();
         }
    else{
        File file = new File(phantomPath);
        String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; cs; rv:1.9.0.8) Gecko/2009032609 Firefox/3.0.8";
        System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", file.getAbsolutePath());
        System.setProperty("phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent", userAgent);

        driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
        }
    driver.get(url);
    try{
        driver.findElement(By.id("membershipNumber")).sendKeys("1234");
        System.out.println("ID input successful");
        if (driver.findElement(By.id("ecuserlogbutton")).isDisplayed()) {
            System.out.println("Login Button is present");
        }
        //This is where it fails with PhantomJS but work with Firefox
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#pintr > #password")).sendKeys("1234");          
        System.out.println("password input successful");
        }
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.print(e.getMessage());
        }
    driver.close();
}
}
```

Comment: It might be timing issues. Try to use Thread.Sleep(2000) before each findElement and observe the behavior. If it works, then you know it's timing issue. Also there is a method called WaitForPagetoLoad. You can call that before you input into elements.

Comment: Well, solved my own problem. Seems like the css selector will not work with PhantomJS I used by.xpath with .//*[@id='password'] and now it works.

Comment: Thanks neo, I actually tried that one too by very slowly debugging the code with eclipse. Still not sure why the css selector is not working.

Comment: But still it's a good practice to check if the document is loaded or checking if an element exists before trying to access it. WebDriver performance might change on different computers. I had situations where tests run fine in one pc, but in another pc fails because of timing issues.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PhantomJS 1.x has a problem with element IDs. The site is broken, because it uses `password` for two elements on the page which should never happen. Simply replacing the id in the selector with the element type (`input`) solves it.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#pintr > input")).sendKeys("1234");
```

Comment: You rock sir! I don't have the reputation to give you a thumbs up, but thanks SO much! I did not notice that the duplicate name for password.

Comment: Yes thanks! I used the screen capture to look at the page but all I saw was the empty field. I guess I would have to do find on the element ID to look for duplicates the next time. Thanks again for your help!!!

Comment: Yes, I also saw the empty field, but I also noticed that somewhere else some text appeared. You will receive an error when the field doesn't exist or is not visible. So that means, when the field should be filled, but is not, you probably selected the wrong field.

Comment: hi, if i have By.id("userid") how i can write your code?

Comment: @AntonioBalduzzi I don't know what you mean. If you can't describe the problem in detail in a comment, it should be a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: @ArtjomB. the problem is the same the driver can't find the element if i use: driver.findElement(By.id("userid"));

Comment: @AntonioBalduzzi It isn't the same case as in this question. Make sure that the element actually exists in the page. Maybe you need to wait for it to appear.

Answer (score 1):

[Try the methods from this link](http://assertselenium.com/2013/01/29/webdriver-wait-commands/)

From my experience with WebDriver, it's usually timing issues. Call the method in above link at the beginning of your code so you can make sure everything loads before you try to find them. Or you can simply use Thread.Sleep with long enough time before finding elements.