# WebdriverJS/IO & PhantomJS - Click handlers with attribute selectors do not work with PhantomJS

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, ghostdriver, webdriver-io

I'm currently working on writing an application test suite with WebdriverJS and PhantomJS.
To ensure that my tests work, I run them via Chrome first, and they all work fine. When I swap out Chrome for PhantomJS however, the tests break.

This question - [WebDriver PhantomJS Unable to find element, but works fine with Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26742014/webdriver-phantomjs-unable-to-find-element-but-works-fine-with-firefox) - appears to outline a very similar problem, but the solution enclosed does not appear to help.

Here's a rough example of the type of thing that works on Chrome, but not on PhantomJS:

```
var client = webdriverjs.remote({ 
    desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome'       
    }, 
    logLevel: 'silent' 
});

client.waitForExist("[data-id='1568911']", function(e){
    client.click("[data-id='1568911']", function(e){
        assert(!e, "Should click on a specific element:" + element);
    });
});
```

When running on PhantomJS, I obviously change the WebdriverJS options first:

```
var client = webdriverjs.remote({ 
    desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'phantomjs',
        'phantomjs.binary.path': "path/to/phantomjs"
    }, 
    logLevel: 'silent' 
});
```

But when I run the tests and set the logLevel to 'verbose', I receive error messages like the one below:

```
[12:43:34]:  COMMAND    POST     "/wd/hub/session/eb2b0a4b-e659-4607-bec0-82209bd6539a/element"
[12:43:34]:  DATA        {"using":"css selector","value":"[data-id='1568911']"}
[12:43:35]:  ERROR  UnknownError    An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
        {"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with css selector '[data-id='1568911']'","request":{"headers":{"Accept-Encoding":"gzip,deflate","Connection":"Keep-Alive","Content-Length":"54","Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","Host":"localhost:12784","User-Agent":"Apache-HttpClient/4.3.2 (java 1.5)"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"using\":\"css selector\",\"value\":\"[data-id='1568911']\"}","url":"/element","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/","path":"/element","relative":"/element","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/element","queryKey":{},"chunks":["element"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/2e1ff0a0-68d7-11e4-ad4c-3105ad572a89/element"}}
```

Why do common CSS2+ selectors like "[data-id='1568911']", or even "#foo", not work on PhantomJS via WebdriverJS? Is it a PhantomJS bug, a WebdriverJS bug, or a mistake I've made in my implementation?

Comment: It's impossible to answer without knowing the page. Have you tried setting the user agent to [Chrome 13](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/8a3f3a95900a3fe800bc) and setting the viewport to something desktop-like, because some sites provide different markup based on size. Have you verified that you are on the correct page by taking a screenshot or printing the source code?

Comment: I know I'm on the correct page, as some of the basic tests pass. I didn't think of the viewport thing, but that appears not to have made a difference. I'm a little confused about the "Chrome 13" user agent thing though. How do I apply that?

Comment: Also hope you don't mind me rolling back your edit of my title. I want to keep a mention of WebdriverIO/JS in there, as I can't be sure if it's causing the issue or not.

Comment: By the way, have you tried to increase the logLevel? Are you sure there aren't any errors? I somehow doubt this is a webdriver-io issue.

Comment: I've set the logLevel to "verbose", which yielded the error message found above. Not sure if there are any further settings for the option. Don't suppose you've been able to recreate this issue yourself?

Comment: Since you don't want to provide your URL, rewrite your script in plain PhantomJS or CasperJS to see if it is a problem with WebdriverIO.

Comment: Ok... So I wrote a quick CSS selector test on Google's home page. this - client.waitForEnabled("#gbqfq", function(e){ assert(!e, "The following element should be in the DOM:" + element);}); - works via WebdriverJS on Chrome, but not on PhantomJS. It's either a bug or an undocumented mode of behaviour in either WebdriverJS, or PhantomJS. Anyone else running into similar issues?

Comment: The google page may be different for every user agent and viewport size. You have to use the correct [phantom user agent string](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/8a3f3a95900a3fe800bc) and a desktop like viewportSize

Comment: The element ID appears to be the same after changing the agent to the one you've linked to. There's definitely a bug in either WebdriverJS, or PhantomJS. It could also possibly be a GhostdriverJS issue. Hard to tell.

Comment: My previous comment was basically like the first one. See [this](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/6ef11c5b2ad7454cc583) script. In plain PhantomJS 1.9.8 this works. So at least for the google page it should mean that WebdriverJS does something wrong with the userAgent string. But that doesn't mean that it is the same issue as for your original page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So at least for the google page it should mean that WebdriverJS does something wrong with the userAgent string. But that doesn't mean that it is the same issue as for your original page.

Something like that...

The default WebdriverJS user agent value is fine. The problem (for the page I was testing on, at least) came from a block of code that looks roughly like this:

```
if(navigator.onLine){ 
    renderPage()
} else doSomethingElse();
```

It appears that PhantomJS always sets navigator.onLine to false...

https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10647

Doh.

That said, I can't understand why anyone would want to use the navigator.onLine value in a product that's always online. One of those classics that can only be found in someone else's code...

Painful bug.

Thanks for the help.